# Inaccuracy when solving problems using FEA

Tags: numerical-methods

I hope this is the correct forum to post this question because I did not find one that really suits this question.

Basically I was reading this paper: [2D Triangular Elements](http://www.unm.edu/~bgreen/ME360/2D%20Triangular%20Elements.pdf)

I like to implement things myself in Java and I did implement the formulas described in the paper. The result looks good (almost).

The first thing was creating a grid which looks like this (ignore the red dot):

[image]

And after solving it using the conjugate gradient method with $\text{res}=10^{-14}$ and after about $5500$ iterations, I get this result:

[image]

This looks alright and from an engineering point of view reasonable but if I zoom in, you can see this result:

[image]

There seems to be some kind of checkerboard pattern. The overall solution seems reasonable but the local solution seems wrong. Especially because elements with a different orientation seem to have a slightly different result.

You might argue that my implementation is wrong but I verified this many many times. Also at the end of the paper is an example with actual numbers which are also returned from my program when I input the grid from the paper.

My question now is:

Is this checkerboard pattern something that occures in FEA or should the result look "smooth"? The paper uses linear elements. Could this be the cause?

I am very happy for any help and/or advice!

Greetings
Finn

Comment: Do you have an analytical solution available?

Comment: I once verified it using a different example where there is nothing but a rod with a load at its end. the displacement at the end was correct to a millimeter

Comment: What are you solving?

Comment: stress/strain in 2d elements

Comment: Can you try solving a much simpler system to see if there are any bugs? Did you write the plotting side of things as well?

Comment: Yes I implememented the plotting myself aswell.

Yeah sure. 1 second

Comment: I guess I would have expected more 'monotonicity' and the regularity suggests a minor bug.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/qnpnbk

The problem also occurs here

Comment: Sorry, first, I am no expert. However, the artifacts in the latter also have that sort of rotation thing going on. Is there anything in the plotting that skips over pairs or anything like that? (A bit vague, I know.)

Comment: No. It's going through all the triangles and the color is calculated for each triangle.
This also happens for irregular grids which I used aswell

Comment: @FinnEggers did you try to solve the problem with different meshes? Or different Solvers? I would suggest solving the same problem with FreeFem++, since you can very easily define the model and access all the FE matrices for comparison.

Comment: No I haven’t done that. I know that their solution looks smoother but they use higher polynomials for interpolation

Comment: @FinnEggers In FreeFem++ you explicitly choose the FE spaces, so you can reproduce your results exactly. Moreover, you can import the FreeFem++ solution to your own visualization module.